# Ideal way to handle multiple socket rooms?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io

So I am creating a chat application and I want to handle multiple chat rooms. Now I watched some tutorials and came up with a way.

```
const io = require("socket.io")(http);
io.on("connection", (socket) => {
    socket.on("joinRoom", (roomid) => {
        //Joining the room
        socket.join(roomid)
        //Broadcasting all previous messages
        io.to(roomid).emit("messages",allPreviousMessages)
    })
    socket.on("chatMessage", (data) => {
        //Saving msg to dB then broadcasting
        io.to(roomid).emit("message",receivedMessage)
    })
    socket.on("disconnect",(data) => {
        //updating user's lastSeen info in dB
    })
})
```

So on my frontend when user clicks on a chatroom we call the "joinRoom" event and connect to the room and on clicking another chatroom make the same process of joining room.
Is this an ideal way for handling multiple chatrooms? If not so please let me know a better solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best way to implement private rooms or channels or chats is this way. I have implemented an example for these three sections.  [Link](https://github.com/TREER00T/Social-Network-Server/blob/main/app/io/connect/socket.js)

Comment: I reveiwed your code so correct me if I'm wrong. You are letting user join single roomsand then disconnecting when he leaves and disconnecting all of them when the socket connection dies. What I didn't get is how did you send previous messages to the chat groups

Comment: This project is designed as a callback function, as you can see, there is a method called validateMessage that is responsible for checking the received json object, so when the json object is received, the data sent through the callback Received and stored in the database.

Comment: I have been reviewing your code can you tell me the flow of your application? Also, have you implemented a notification feature? Actually, I'm facing some issues with when to connect/disconnect and whether to join all rooms together or one by one .

Answer (score 0):

User token and api must be authenticated before connecting to socket.io. If this part is ok it will connect to socket.io otherwise it can't cause you to see the event that is there. Something happens by calling each of them. For example, by calling this onNotificationForVoiceCall event, the received data is first checked, then it is checked whether this user is present in the list of online users or not, and the state of the next step is checked. Whether or not this room has already been created in the database, the response of all these operations is returned to the user by socket.emit,

And I fixed some bug in project.